# How to create separate files for functions, then import them?

Tags: python, function, file, import, python-telegram-bot

I have this working code:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext

updater = Updater('token')

def hello(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Hello!')

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('hello', hello))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

I wish to have a separate file for each function and have a *main.py* where I import them.

So I head to create a *f1.py* with just this:

```
def hello(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Hello!')
```

Then import it into a *main.py* with

```
from f1 import hello
hello()
```

Obviously, this is not working (missing arguments). How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Can you show us how are your files structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main.py` and `f1.py` are fine, but on `updater.dispatcher` of your `main.py` something is missing. Try this:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext

#On my bots I prefer to import the entire module than a function from a module,
#because I usually have users.py (all functions for users), clients.py (all 
#functions for clients), devs.py (all functions for developer's team) and so on
import f1

updater = Updater('token')

#Calling a function from a module must have a callback, as shown bellow
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('hello', callback = f1.hello))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Try this and let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!!

Answer (score 0):

For more informations, here is a good source for import own modules:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html